# Assign the same JsonProperty to two properties on class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

When deserializing a JSON property from a request I want to use it for two different properties on my object. e.g;

```
public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "favoriteColor")]
    public string favoriteColor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "favoriteColor")]
    public string oldFavoriteColor { get; set; }
}
```

However this causes an error:

> A member with the name 'favoriteColor' already exists on 'Example'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.

How do I do this when that's exactly what I intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better answer that involves taking a step back from the problem and seeing whether there's a totally different approach. In particular, **why do you need a class that has two properties with the same value?** Other than deserializing from JSON, will every other consumer of this class know that these two properties need to be kept in sync, and why?

But this answers the immediate question.

The `[JsonProperty]` attribute is used for both serializing and deserializing. If you had two properties with the same `[JsonProperty]` attribute then when you serialized the object to JSON you would have two properties with the same name.

You can create a custom JSON serializer like this. As you can see, after an `Example` is deserialized it will populate the `favoriteColor` property with the value of the `oldFavoriteColor` property.

```
public class ExampleConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Example>
{
    public override Example Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Example();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var result = (Example)base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, 
            serializer);
        result.favoriteColor = result.oldFavoriteColor;
        return result;
    }
}
```

In order for this to work you also have to tell the serializer not to attempt to deserialize the `favoriteColor` property. Even without the `[JsonProperty]` attribute there's still a conflict between `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "favoriteColor")]` and another property actually named "favoriteColor."

```
public class Example
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string favoriteColor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "favoriteColor")]
    public string oldFavoriteColor { get; set; }
}
```

A unit test to confirm:

```
public void DeserializerPopulatesFavoriteColorFromOldFavoriteColor()
{
    var json = @"{ favoriteColor: ""Green""}";
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json, new ExampleConverter());
    Assert.AreEqual("Green", deserialized.oldFavoriteColor);
    Assert.AreEqual(deserialized.oldFavoriteColor, deserialized.favoriteColor);
}
```

Comment: So in regards to "you also have to tell the serializer not to attempt to deserialize" your saying if the incoming property was `color` instead of one that exists on the target object; then `favoriteColor` and `oldFavoriteColor ` could have their own `CustomCreationConverter`s and it should work?

Comment: If you have a property named "favoriteColor" and then a property with a different name, but with the attribute `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "favoriteColor")]`, you'll get the same error as in your question. In order to use a custom converter you first have to still have to weed out those issues. You can't have competing/conflicting property names and attributes. Once you get that part sorted out you can do pretty much whatever else you want in the custom converter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could modify the set method for one of the properties so that whenever it is set, it also sets the other property

e.g.

```
public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "favoriteColor")]
    public string favoriteColor { 
      get { return favoriteColor; }
      set
      {
        favoriteColor = value;
        if (oldFavoriteColor == null) {
          oldFavoriteColor = value;
        }
      }
    }

    public string? oldFavoriteColor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Modificaiton of the Set might go overboard. It can have unwanted side effects. JSON is a approach for Serialsiation. So providing a custom Serialise/Deserialize function might be better here. This is simply outside what the automatic can do for you. In this specific case (color and old color) it might work. But I would prefer setting it to a none/other specific value indicating not having had set it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I tried the alternative approach, a custom serializer. This solution (modifying `Set`) a) uses fewer lines of code, and b) ensures that the properties actually stay in sync. The underlying problem to me is having two properties with the same value. It's guaranteed confusion for future developers if they see two nearly-identical properties and they waste time guessing which one to use or digging through the code trying to figure out how they get populated.